# Delete rows from a pandas DataFrame based on a conditional expression, iteration (n) and (n+1)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iteration

Given a dataframe as follows:

```
 col1 
1  0.6   
2  0.88  
3  1.2  
4  1.2  
5  1.2  
6  0.55  
7  0.55
8  0.65
```

I want to delete rows from it where the value in row (n+1) is **the same value** in (n), such that this would yield:

```
col1 
1  0.6   
2  0.88  
3  1.2  
4  row deleted  
5  row deleted  
6  0.55  
7  row deleted
8  0.65
```

Comment: You can use 
any of the proposed solutions , or `df = df.mask(df['col1'].eq(df['col1'].shift(1)))` if you want NaN

Answer (score 2):

```
In [191]: df[df["col1"] != df["col1"].shift()]
Out[191]:
   col1
1  0.60
2  0.88
3  1.20
6  0.55
8  0.65
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
df = df[~df['col1'].eq(df['col1'].shift(1))]
print(df)

   col1
0  0.60
1  0.88
2  1.20
5  0.55
7  0.65
```

Or:

```
df = df[df['col1'].ne(df['col1'].shift(1))]
print(df)

   col1
0  0.60
1  0.88
2  1.20
5  0.55
7  0.65
```

Comment: the second method doesn't work , for example 1,1,2,1,1 .....should be 1,2,1

Comment: I don't understand, isn't there a `keep='first'` by default in `drop_duplicates` method?

Comment: yes but drop_duplicates does not take into account that they have to be continuous

Comment: I think `df = df[~df['col1'].eq(df['col1'].shift(1))]` is the solution , 
or @WenYoBen's solution if you don't want to generalize to string

Comment: Ok got it. Makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Ok let do

```
df=df[df.diff().ne(0)]
```